# Dropbox going into failure when simulator option 'Reset Content And Settings' clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

Images upload and download is done and if I restart the app by deleting from simulator then also everything working properly. But, if click 'Reset Content And Settings' of simulator and build the program again it is going into failure method. The output is :-

```
 [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files_put/sandbox/new.jpg - (401) Authentication failed
```

2016-07-18 16:37:08.145 DropBox[2522:150093] File upload failed with error: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=401 "(null)" UserInfo={error=Authentication failed, sourcePath=/Users/hsdb/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E50DACC5-9094-4F27-B98D-C58902A2B7B0/data/Containers/Data/Application/BC61504E-C06E-41D3-B5D3-6FF55F98128A/Documentsnew.jpg, destinationPath=/image.jpg}

Answer (score 0):

Reset on the simulator clears it to the initial state. The error message you posted says authentication is failing, which is correct given the system has been cleared.

Comment: After reset when, I login into it then also it is going to failure. and if i stop and rebuild the program then everything is working fine .. but it is showing problem in first time after resetting ?

Comment: Can't help any further without seeing the relevant code. Both startup and auth code are going to matter